# Duration of $_POST Content (Lifetime)

Tags: php, http, post

This is a relatively simple question to which I haven't been able to find the answer (or my search skills are just rubbish), say I send `$_POST` content through `jQuery/AJAX`, the content is handled by `PHP` and a result is returned, finishing this function.

How long does this `$_POST` content still "live"? Is it "destroyed" as soon as the `AJAX` / `PHP` function is done?

Or does it remain in the system for a while?

Comment: It exists only for the life of the transaction.

Comment: @Dave, Many thanks for your quick response!

Comment: PHP is a stateless language so `$_POST` is registered at the beginning of the script invocation and is removed once the script is finished processing.

Comment: If you want to store data longer than 1 request you should use a database or the `$_SESSION`variable: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, so the web server does not need to keep any data for the duration of multiple requests. When your web server sends multiple requests to PHP (usually [PHP-FPM](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)), it treats every request separately.

So if you send an HTTP POST request (which has a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`) to PHP, the data will be loaded into `$_POST` before your script is executed. You can access it while your script is running, but afterwards all variables are deleted from memory, including [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

If you want to use data across multiple requests, you need to persist it somehow, for example using [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), files, databases, shared memory, [APCu](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.apcu.php).